# How to request Ebox wifi with modbus

Tags: modbus, modbus-tcp, pymodbus, pymodbustcp

I've never used modbus before.

I have an `eBox-Wifi` `Epever` connected to an MPPT charge controller TRIRON for solar power.

I was able to make it connect to my wifi and now has an accessible IP : `192.168.39.149`

I just want to extract some data from it, battery Voltage, etc...

On `http://192.168.39.149:80`, i have a web interface for administration. (Which is not what i want.)

After an `nmap`, I see that there is port 8088 open. (Can use modbus there maybe ? no web interface on this port.)

I installed and used `modbus_cli` like that `modbus -b 115200 -p 1 192.168.39.149:8088 3101` but I can't make it return anything...

https://files.i4wifi.cz/inc/_doc/attach/StoItem/7068/MODBUS-Protocol-v25.pdf

http://www.solar-elektro.cz/data/dokumenty/1733_modbus_protocol.pdf

https://github.com/favalex/modbus-cli

EDIT : I changed for baud 9600 and port 502. (Which are the defaults for modbus ?)
[image]

Comment: I use EPEVER controllers but have avoided these WIFI units because the docs ([manual](https://www.epever.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/eBox-WIFI-01-Manual-EN-V2.0.pdf), [datasheet](https://www.epever.com/product/ebox-wifi-01-wifi-serial-server/)) make no mention of Modbus support. I'd suggest [asking EPEVER](https://www.epever.com/contact/) directly.

Comment: @Brits Are you using something like a "Epever CC-USB-RS485-150U" usb/rj45 cable instead ? I really need to find a way to extract raw data with rpi from my MPPT.

Comment: We wire our own cables; mainly deploy tracer3215bn units which appear to have the same rs485 connector as the Triton units. Have not tried this with a pi but an rs485 hat should work (I suspect the epever cables will also be ok).

Comment: @Brits I have seen some code with IP and this 8088 port like here : https://github.com/gabrielpc1190/Home-Assistant_EPEver-eBox-Wifi-01-MODBUS But I'm not using home assistant, i just want to send a request from command line. Don't know how to use Modbus :(

Comment: I saw that too - it's important to note that it appears to be using Modbus RTU over TCP (which differs from Modbus TCP). However the example seems somewhat incomplete and there is no real documentation. I'd suggest asking Epever, I've found their support team to be pretty good.

Comment: Note that the baud rate relates to communication between the eBox-WIFI and the controller - the EPEVER units I work with all use 115200 (there is an option to change this but it does not work!). If you can communicate with the unit using the EPEVER Android app then the baud rate is set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try python [modpoll](https://github.com/gavinying/modpoll) tool with the following configuration, install modpoll via `pip install modpoll` if not installed.

- Create a local config file, e.g. `epever.csv`, only added voltage/current/power values for testing.

  ```
  device,mydevice,1,,,
  poll,holding_register,12544,4,BE_LE,
  ref,PV_array_input_voltage,12544,uint16,r,V,0.01
  ref,PV_array_input_current,12545,uint16,r,A,0.01
  ref,PV_array_input_power,12546,uint32,r,W,0.01
  ```
- poll local device,

  ```sh
  modpoll --tcp 192.168.39.149 --tcp-port 8088 --config epever.csv
  ```

> The configuration assumes you keep the device ID = `1` (default), and use `BE_LE` endian, please adjust endian setting according to the platform running on.

Comment: I just have an error : `2021-12-26 20:41:05,832 | I | modpoll.main |  ====== modpoll polling at rate:5.0s, actual:5.0s ======
2021-12-26 20:41:09,369 | E | modpoll.modbus_task | Reading device:mydevice, FuncCode:3, Start_address:12544, Size:4... ERROR
===== references from device: mydevice =====
failed to poll device: mydevice
Done.`

Comment: The error is the same if I replace 8088 by another port or even another IP. Communication isn't established...

Comment: I've changed baud to 9600 which seems to be the default but same... and port 502. (I've added screenshot from parameters.)

Comment: The port is open, and hanging in a browser, so something is running on it, but i can't take anything from it. :/

Comment: the baudrate shall be set according to your TRIRON device, if you didn't change, default setting is 115200; while the tcp-server port setting will decide which port to connect from your client, in this case, if you set to 502, then change the command arguments to `--tcp-port 502`

Comment: Reverted, but still the same problem persist. Connection doesn't seem to be established.

Comment: Could you make sure the device is working? like read some values via their web interface or application? if so, you can use wireshark to see the correct communication packets for TCP side of ebox, and use serial port sinifer tool for the other side if necessary. Once you know the correct format, then adjust your client tool accordingly.

Comment: Device working normally with phone app in AP mode (With data I'm interested in). In STA Mode it connects successfully to my home wifi, has an IP 192.168.39.149, and the web admin interface is working well on port 80. But didn't answer any requests from the tcp server port (8088 or 502). Something is there because the port is clearly open... but modpoll request and co (tcpmodbus.py, modbus_cli...) are failing to return any data. (I will try wireshark later today)

Comment: Basically, i can extract the data only with the phone app. (But AP only)

Comment: I surrendered and bought a RS485 usb cable. :(

Comment: anyway thx for answering, I'll delete this question soon.

Comment: Please don't delete the question (the fact that you could not get this working may be useful to others who want to trey the same thing in the future).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need more than the graph for EPever Solar Station.
That is what I use and it works really good.
I connect STA mode Not AP.
I create a virtual COM9 port Baut Rate 115200, 192.168.0.7 :8088.
I create a new SSID:LSD Passw. 12345678 in the router assign a static IP 192.168.0.7
I used android app "PortTester" and I see IP 192.168.0.7 port 8088 is open fast and simple. Follow this video like I did...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RrEumwFHfJ4
What I try to do is integrate it in Home Assistant.

Comment: Based upon this I'd guess that port 8088 is Modbus RTU over TCP because I'm pretty sure that the EPEVER application uses Modbus RTU (mentioned this possibility in a comment above)

Answer (score 0):

I see something here, it since to be someone has connect...
https://community.home-assistant.io/t/epever-modbus-rs-485-config/214397/3

I don't know if this work?

modbus:

- type: tcp
  host: 10.240.1.4
  port: 8088
  name: epever4
  timeout: 2
- type: rtuovertcp
  host: 10.240.1.4
  port: 8088
  name: epever4